# How would you approach this question on definite integral?

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals

> $$\int_{\frac \pi 4}^{\frac \pi 2}\left(2\cos\left(\frac x 2\right) - e^{-x}\right)^2dx$$

I have tried expanding it and then do the integral but it leads to $4 cos(\frac{x}{2})e^{-x}$ in the middle term of the expansion.

Am i missing something? Is there a "trick" to this? If so how would you approach the question? What are the things that i should keep in mind solving this kind of question? PS. the answer to this is $1.41$

Comment: Hello and welcome to the site. You will do good to learn MathJax typesetting as it is not popular to just post image files of questions. There is a tutorial here on the site somewhere. It is mostly the same syntax as LaTeX typesetting.

Answer (score 3):

There are (at least) two ways.  First,

$$\int e^{ax}\cos bx \; dx$$ is a standard integral done in most calculus texts.  The trick is to integrate by parts twice and then solve the resulting equation for the integral you want.

Second, you can substitute

$$\cos bx = \frac{e^{ibx} + e^{-ibx}}{2}$$

and multiply everything out. You then just have to integrate exponential functions (and deal with the complex numbers.)

Comment: Hey sir thanks for your answer! Also, i wanted to ask Is this kind of question common when one just started doing calculus, is this considered as an easy question? (this appeared in the non-calculator section in my textbook!)

Comment: The first way is shown in most calculus texts, so you'd learn it in either Calc 1 or Calc 2.  The average student wouldn't be expected to come up with the trick on his own, but he'd be expected to learn it.

Answer (score 2):

$$\int_{\frac{\pi}{4}}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\left(2\cos\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)-e^{-x}\right)^{2}dx=\int_{\frac{\pi}{4}}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\left(4\cos^{2}\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)+e^{-2x}-4\cos\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)e^{-x}\right)dx$$$$=4\int_{\frac{\pi}{4}}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\cos^{2}\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)dx+\int_{\frac{\pi}{4}}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}e^{-2x}dx-4\int_{\frac{\pi}{4}}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\cos\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)e^{-x}dx$$$$=2\color{green}{\int_{\frac{\pi}{4}}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}1+\cos\left(x\right)dx}+\color{blue}{\int_{\frac{\pi}{4}}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}e^{-2x}dx}-4\color{red}{\int_{\frac{\pi}{4}}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}e^{-x}\cos\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)dx}$$

For the red part (**where you have a problem with**) using integration by parts we have:
$$\text{I}=\int_{\frac{\pi}{4}}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}e^{-x}\cos\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)dx$$$$=-e^{-x}\cos \left(\frac{x}{2}\right)\Big|_\frac{\pi}{4}^\frac{\pi}{2}-\frac{1}{2}\int_{\frac{\pi}{4}}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}e^{-x}\sin\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)dx$$$$=-e^{-x}\cos\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)\Big|_\frac{\pi}{4}^\frac{\pi}{2}-\frac{1}{2}\left[-e^{-x}\sin\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)\Big|_\frac{\pi}{4}^\frac{\pi}{2}+\frac{1}{2}\int_{\frac{\pi}{4}}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}e^{-x}\cos\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)dx\right]$$$$=-e^{-x}\cos\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)\Big|_\frac{\pi}{4}^\frac{\pi}{2}+\frac{1}{2}e^{-x}\sin\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)\Big|_\frac{\pi}{4}^\frac{\pi}{2}-\frac{1}{4}\underbrace{\int_{\frac{\pi}{4}}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}e^{-x}\cos\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)dx}_\textrm{I}$$

Hence

$$\int_{\frac{\pi}{4}}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\cos\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)e^{-x}dx=\frac{4}{5}\left(-e^{-x}\cos\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)\Big|_\frac{\pi}{4}^\frac{\pi}{2}+\frac{1}{2}e^{-x}\sin\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)\Big|_\frac{\pi}{4}^\frac{\pi}{2}\right)\simeq \color{red}{{0.208396}
}$$

For the blue part setting $-2x \mapsto u$ follows:
$$\int_{\frac{\pi}{4}}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}e^{-2x}dx=\frac{1}{2}\int_{-\pi}^{-\frac{\pi}{2}}e^{u}du=\frac{1}{2}\left(e^{\left(-\frac{\pi}{2}\right)}-e^{\left(-\pi\right)}\right)\simeq \color{blue}{0.0823328290435}$$

For the green part using some elementary integrals follows:

$$\int_{\frac{\pi}{4}}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}1+\cos\left(x\right)dx=\frac{\pi}{2}-\frac{\pi}{4}+\sin\left(\frac{\pi}{2}\right)-\sin\left(\frac{\pi}{4}\right)\simeq \color{green}{1.07829138221}$$

Summing the results gives the final answer:

$$2\left(1.07829138221\right)+\left(0.0823328290435\right)-4\left({0.208396}
\right)=1.4053315934635
$$

Which is the the answer you mentioned.

Comment: This answer is fantastic!

Comment: Also i wanted to ask, is this "integration by parts" a concept that is taught in the beginning? Because our class just started doing calculus and it seems like this concept is not in the syllabus. Many Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

$$\int e^{ax}\cos(bx)dx = \frac{e^{ax}}{a^2+b^2}\left(a\cos bx+b\sin bx\right)$$

Here $a = -1, b = \frac12$

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:**

Integrate $$\int \cos\left(\frac x2\right)\exp(-x)\,\mathrm dx$$ by parts twice. The first time, let $f = \cos\left(\dfrac x2\right)$ and $g' = \exp(-x)$. The second time, let $f = -\sin\left(\dfrac x2\right)$ and $g' = \dfrac{\exp(-x)}4$.